# limit df to people with valuesstarting at x only

Tags: r, dataframe, row

I have a df as follows

```
 names numbers
1   john      -3
2   john      -2
3   john      -1
4   john       1
5   john       2
6   mary      -2
7   mary      -1
8   mary       1
9   mary       2
10  mary       3
11   tom      -1
12   tom       1
13   tom       2
14   tom       3
```

I want to limit the df to people who have a value that begins with -3. Then I want to do the same for -2 and then the same again for people who start off with a value of -1. My end result would be three dfs, one each for john, mary and tom given that they all have different starting values (-3,-2 and -1).

e.g., for mary

```
  names numbers
6   mary      -2
7   mary      -1
8   mary       1
9   mary       2
10  mary       3
```

my real dataframe has about 10,000 people in it so I can't just filter out by name as i'm doing here. I'd like a way of doing it by number, something like

```
df1<-df[df$number>=-3,]   ##too simplistic
```

but this pulls in all the rows for everyone in the dataframe (logical considering they all have values > -3). I want the code to limit the resultant df to just the person who had a starting value of -3 and then all their values underneath that as shown for mary above.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `ave` to calculate the first number for each group, then `split` on it.

```
df$first <- ave(df$numbers, df$names, FUN=function(x) x[1])
split(df, f = df$first)
```

yields:

```
$`-3`
  i names numbers first
1 1  john      -3    -3
2 2  john      -2    -3
3 3  john      -1    -3
4 4  john       1    -3
5 5  john       2    -3

$`-2`
    i names numbers first
6   6  mary      -2    -2
7   7  mary      -1    -2
8   8  mary       1    -2
9   9  mary       2    -2
10 10  mary       3    -2

$`-1`
    i names numbers first
11 11   tom      -1    -1
12 12   tom       1    -1
13 13   tom       2    -1
14 14   tom       3    -1
```

Comment: brilliant - thanks a million for this. Rather than split, I'll just use df1<-df[df$first==-3,] so that I can make my separate dfs. Feel silly that I didn't think of assigning an indicator to each person! Thank you for pointing me along my way!

Comment: @user2363642, what are you really planning to do with the data? Usually, it's better to keep it in a list of data frames (as in the answer) than to create many separate data frames in the global environment. You could also consider using e.g. dplyr to do by-group operations very efficiently.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I want to run a regression on each subgroup... still possible with dplyr?